# Invalid argument in code while using text file in code

Tags: php

I am getting below error while executing php

PHP Warning:

> file_get_contents(G:\PleskVhostsxpertadvisorfree.com\httpdocs\upload/test.txt):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\expertadvisorfree.com\httpdocs\force_download.php on
>   line 31

Below is the code

```
$file = file("G:\PleskVhosts\expertadvisorfree.com\httpdocs\upload/test.txt");
$file = trim($file);
file_put_contents($file, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the file location. You're using both normal and inverted bars in the address. `\` `/`

You should change the file's physical address to the correct bars.

```
$file = file("G:\PleskVhosts\expertadvisorfree.com\httpdocs\upload\test.txt");
```

Comment: I have replaced code with code given by you for $file now it is giving me error  PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in G:\PleskVhosts\expertadvisorfree.com\httpdocs\force_download.php on line 24

Comment: That's because [file()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php) returns an array, trim must receive a string as a parameter. Perhaps you'd like to trim the string inside the `file()` function.